# image rotation with Sphnix reStructuredText

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I include a image using Sphinx on a Windows 10 machine using the following command

```
.. image:: pic.jpg
```

The image is included fine, but the orientation is off. I tried rotate the image using windows build-in image viewer but it does not have any effect for my image rendering.

What am I missing?